# modifying url to display more results per page

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview, urlhacks

How would one find out if it's even possible on specific site?
For example https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=topics&f=257

There are many more sites where I wanted to display more results per page but option is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowledge of the code base, there is no way to know whether you can change the page behavior via a URL parameter, other than trial and error.

If the site is well designed, all URL parameters ought to be validated against a white list, so it should not be possible to hack the URL.  So you should not rely on this.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not answering the real question and i know that John Wu is right: You can't obtain this via querystring if you don't know if this is coded server side. What i think is that there is always a way:
For example, in this case you can use rss feed (the button placed at the bottom of the page): 
https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=rsstopic&pg=Topics&f=257